# Why isn't JCombobox a subclass of AbstractButton?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance

`AbstractButton` defines the method `addActionListener`. `JButton` and several other common classes inherit it.

I'm in a position where I want to write a method which takes an array of objects that support `addActionListener`, takes an `ActionListener`, and adds the action listener to all these objects. So I wrote the method like so:

```
private void addActionListener(ActionListener listener, AbstractButton... buttons){
    for(AbstractButton button : buttons)
        button.addActionListener(listener);
}
```

However some of these objects that I'm trying to pass in this method, are `JCombobox` instances. They do have a method `addActionListener` that does exactly what it does in `AbstractButton` subclasses. But for some reason, `JCombobox` doesn't inherit from `AbstractButton`.

This forces me to use the Adapter pattern, in order to wrap the incompatible `JCombobox`es in objects that do inherit `AbstractButton`:

```
private static class ComboBoxListenableAdapter extends AbstractButton {
    JComboBox combobox;
    public ComboBoxListenableAdapter (JComboBox combobox){
        this.combobox = combobox;
    }
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener){
        combobox.addActionListener(listener);
    }
}
```

My question is: why doesn't `JCombobox` inherit `AbstractButton`? Doesn't it make sense?

Comment: Why should a combobox inherit the behaviour of a button? They both accept `ActionListner`, yes, but else?

Comment: So at least since action listeners are a fundamental concept in GUI, why note make a `Listenable` interface and have several classes implement it? I don't know, just seems weird

Comment: Because, it doesn't make sense for it to do so. JComboBox isn't a button, it doesn't share many of the stateful requirements of button

Comment: You might need to provide an additional method that take JComboBox as well

Comment: Because that's the way they designed it. Ask them. All you will get here is more or less uninformed guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because JComboBox isn't an AbstractButton. Now it may have made sense to make both AbstractButton and JComboBox both some interface defined as `ActionListenerAccepter` or something like that, but that just wasn't the way the two classes were defined.

Assuming you want a solution of having one method (if not use overloaded methods like suggested), I would just use instanceof in this case to keep your code simple (avoiding something like that Adapter you have).

```
private void addActionListener(ActionListener listener,
          JComponent... possibleActionListenerComponents)
{
    for(JComponent c : possibleActionListenerComponents)
        if (c instanceof AbstractButton)
            ((AbstractButton)c).addActionListener(listener);
        else if (c instanceof JComboBox)
            ((JComboBox)c).addActionListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: Well, I guess it's just me, but I would more prefer overloaded methods that accepts the different `JComponent` subtypes instead of checking and casting them in every iteration.

Comment: @Tom That's a better approach but I am under the impression Prog wanted a solution of one method.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove And I want a pony, we don't always get what we want ;)